# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class on DexPathList

Tags: android, google-play-services, apk, classpath, dex

I am packaging several Google Play Services jars (gcm & auth) into an Adobe AIR for Android app.  I obtained the relevant jars from the **aar** files that are provided with these Play Services libs.  I placed these jars into the **app/libs** folder in my project, and compiled the apk.  However, when I launch the apk, I get this error in logcat:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/air.com.me.andros-1/base.apk"]

This error happens when I try to invoke `GooglePlayServicesUtil` in my java code.  However, this error doesn't make sense, as clearly GooglePlayServicesUtil is present in my apk when I reverse-engineered it with **Apktool**.  See these screenshots:

[image]

.

[image]

Anybody run into a similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem!
It turns out that `GooglePlayServicesUtil.class` extends an obfuscated class called **zze**.  This **zze.class** resides in `app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-basement/9.4.0/`.  So I had to manually copy this jar containing this `zze` class into my app/libs folder before building the final apk with Adobe AIR.